# ¿Cómo pintar celdas en base a una condición en excel?

Tags: excel

tengo una consulta

Lo que quiero es validar si  la suma de los valores de un determinado Proyecto UO resulta 9 que pinte las celda de todos los valores que se sumaron en excel

Ejemplo:

```
Proyecto UO           2019-10-01
100221                 9          pintar de verde
100221                 0          pintar de verde
                     -----------
                       9 => respuesta si obtiene 9, entonces se pinta todas celdas que se sumaron por día.


Proyecto UO           2019-10-01
115235                 3          pintar de verde
115235                 3          pintar de verde
115235                 3          pintar de verde
                     -----------
                       9 => respuesta si obtiene 9, entonces se pinta todas celdas que se sumaron por día
```

Aquí muestro una imagen del excel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Veo que sus previas preguntas son sobre manejar Excel usando C# y Epplus. Por esta pregunta: cual es el fuente de data (los 9 y 0)? Ingresada por usuario en el archivo Excel? O creada por un programa c#?

Comment: lo que pido es como manejarlo desde el excel no C# ni epplus, como podría validarlo unicamente por excel.

Comment: Cual es el lenguaje de su Excel? espanol o ingles?

Comment: lenguaje español españa

Answer (score 0):

Puede utilizar el *Formato Condicional* para lograrlo.

El imagen de abajo es mi ejemplo de data. Los valores del proyecto `100221` se sumaron a 9, y los valores del proyecto `100500` solo se sumaron a 7.

[image: Ejemplo de data]

---

**El primero**, tenemos que crear una *tabla de referencia* para guardar el informacion de si la suma de los valores de un Proyecto UO es igual a 9 o no.
Estos son los pasos:

1. Copiar todos los Proyectos UO en la columna A y pegarlos en una celda vacia (en mi caso: F2). Y selecciona en el menu bar: *Datos > Quitar Duplicados*

[image: Quitar duplicados]

2. Poner los titulos en celdas F1 y G1. Puede hacerlo como asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3. En la celda G2, calculamos si la suma de los valores del proyecto `100221` es igual a 9, utilizando la formula `=SUMAR.SI(rangos_de_Proyecto, $F2, rangos_de_valores)=9`. 
   En este caso: `=SUMAR.SI($A$2:$A$6, $F2, $B$2:$B$6)=9`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4. Copiar la formula a las celdas debajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Ahora realizamos el **Formato Condicional**:

1. Selecciona la celda B2, y en el menu bar selecciona: *Inicio > Formato condicional > Nueva regla*
2. Selecciona "*Utilice una formula que determine las celdas para aplicar formato*".
3. Ingresa la formula para obtener data de la tabla de referencia: `=BUSCARV(valor_buscado, rango_de_tabla_de_referencia, indicador_columnas, FALSO)` . En este caso: `=BUSCARV($A2,$F$2:$G$3,2,FALSO)`
4. Hace click en el boton *Formato*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5. Selecciona el color y hace click *Aceptar*, y *Aceptar*. Esto paso aplica el formato para la celda B2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

6. Finalmente, para aplicar el formato a otras celdas, hace doble click en *Copiar Formato* y selecciona las celdas debajo de B2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los valores de `1000221` se pintada de verde.